# How to get team entities details in other main entities in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, entity

I have two entities `Team`, `MainEntry`. Now  I want to get all team details in dropdown while entring in MainEntry view 
in MVC.
In other word in the MainEntry views I want get all team details in the dropdown.
Im using VS-2015, MVC5, EF6 with Code first migration.

```
 public class Team
    {     
        public int TeamId { get; set; }
        public string TeamName { get; set; }
        public string TeamAge { get; set; }
        public string TeamLocation { get; set; }    
     }


 public class MainEntry
 {     
        public int MainEntryId { get; set; }
        public string TeamAssignment { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
        public string Series { get; set; }  
        public string Stock { get; set; } 
        public string Points { get; set; }
        public sting Teamname {get; set;}   //(dropdown fill)
        public string Teamage {get;set;}    //(dropwon fill)
        public string TeamLocation {get;set;} //(dropwon fill)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can populate your dropdown list like

```
ViewBag.Teamnames = _db.Team.Select(c => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = c.Teamname ,
                    Value = c.MainEntryId.ToString(),
                    Selected = true
                });
```

and in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "TeamName", 
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Teamnames, 
    new { style = "max-width: 600px;" }
)
```

Another way

I usually create a view model that contains both the model if you want collection in model you can change your model as below and update your migration configuration file

```
 public class MainEntry  {     
        public int MainEntryId { get; set; }
        public string TeamAssignment { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
        public string Series { get; set; }  
        public string Stock { get; set; } 
        public string Points { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Team> Teamname { get; set; }//(dropwon fill)
        public IEnumerable<Team> Teamage //(dropwon fill)
        public IEnumerable<Team> TeamLocation //(dropwon fill)  }
```